# How to automate retry on an R script in PowerShell when the connection breaks

Tags: r, powershell, twitter

I have code for PowerShell that runs an R script. The script is supposed to be scraping Twitter. Unfortunately, the connection with Twitter is breaking down, and I have to manually re-run the script. Is it possible to run the script automatically once the Twitter connection breaks so that I do not have to sit and monitor it?

Following is my PowerShell code.

```
cd C:\Program` Files\R\R-3.2.0\bin

Get-Content C:\Users\Lab-User\Documents\Sentiment_Twitter\Trial.R | .\R.exe --save
```

Comment: does it provide any sort of error that it isn't connected to Twitter anymore?

Comment: It gives me the following message "Connection to the twitter stream was closed after 7248 seconds with up to 27000 tweets downloaded". The quantitative information provided is not always consistent. One time the, I checked it in the mid night and the connection was closed then it provided the following message "Connection to the twitter stream was closed after 9000 seconds with up to 24000 tweets downloaded."

Comment: I believe there is a way to have powershell check and if the return is "..." then run a command, you might look into this and if I get a chance I will reply with anything I find.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be easier to just create a loop. If the connections breaks then the loop will start over again. For this create a batch file. and enter the following

```
@echo off
cls
:start
powershell.exe -Command "Get-Content C:\Users\Samarth\Documents\Twitter\Trial.R | C:\Program` Files\R\R- 3.2.0\bin\R.exe --save"
goto start
```